# Static local variables in Perl

Tags: perl, scope

I'm looking for advice on Perl best practices. I wrote a script which had a complicated regular expression:

```
my $regex = qr/complicated/;

# ...

sub foo {
  # ...

  if (/$regex/)
  # ...
}
```

where `foo` is a function which is called often, and `$regex` is not used outside that function.  What is the best way to handle situations like this?  I only want it to be interpreted once, since it's long and complicated.  But it seems a bit questionable to have it in global scope since it's only used in that sub. Is there a reasonable way to declare it static?

A similar issue arises with another possibly-unjustified global. It reads in the current date and time and formats it appropriately. This is also used many times, and again only in one function. But in this case it's even more important that it not be re-initialized, since I want all instances of the date-time to be the same from a given invocation of the script, even if the minutes roll over during execution.

At the moment I have something like

```
my ($regex, $DT);

sub driver {
  $regex = qr/complicated/;
  $DT = dateTime();
  # ...
}

# ...

driver();
```

which at least slightly segregates it. But perhaps there are better ways.

Again: I'm looking for the right way to do this, in terms of following best practices and Perl idioms. Performance is nice but readability and other needs take priority if I can't have everything.

Comment: Ack! Please say `my ($regex, $DT)` not `my $regex, $DT`! (`use warnings` will catch this. `use strict` will catch this more harshly)

Comment: For regexes in particular, see ikegami's answer; for all other cases, see hobbs's.

Comment: @mob: Good catch. My actual code had it right, but the summary I typed was incorrect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're using perl 5.10+, use a `state` variable.

```
use feature 'state';
# use 5.010; also works

sub womble {
    state $foo = something_expensive();
    return $foo ** 2;
}
```

will only call `something_expensive` once.

If you need to work with older perls, then use a lexical variable in an outer scope with an extra pair of braces:

```
{
    my $foo = something_expensive();
    sub womble {
        return $foo ** 2;
    }
}
```

this keeps `$foo` from leaking to anyone except for `womble`.

Comment: `state` was introduced in 5.10, not 5.12.  ([Dev release 5.9.4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl594delta.html#state%28%29-variables), actually.)

Comment: The trick with the lexical-scoped variable will only work _if the variable assignment is executed_. If you typically put your subroutines down the bottom of your main file then the assignment will only be executed when the program flow reaches it.

Answer (score 18):

Is there any interpolation in the pattern? If not, the pattern will only be compiled once no matter how many times the qr// is executed.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/foo/ for 1..10' 2>&1 | grep Compiling | wc -l
1

$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/foo$_/ for 1..10' 2>&1 | grep Compiling | wc -l
10
```

Even if there is interpolation, the pattern will only be compiled if the interpolated variables have changed.

```
$ perl -Mre=debug -e'$x=123; qr/foo$x/ for 1..10;' 2>&1 | grep Compiling | wc -l
1

$ perl -Mre=debug -e'qr/foo$_/ for 1..10' 2>&1 | grep Compiling | wc -l
10
```

Otherwise, you can use

```
{
   my $re = qr/.../;
   sub foo {
      ...
      /$re/
      ...
   }
}
```

or

```
use feature qw( state );
sub foo {
   state $re = qr/.../;
   ...
   /$re/
   ...
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer that answers the true spirit of the user's problem (only compiling a complicated regex once). Using a state variable is a good general solution, but for regexes should not be needed.

Answer (score 4):

Regexes can be specified with the "o" modifier, which says "compile pattern once only" - in the 3rd. edition of the Camel, see p. 147

Answer (score 1):

There's a [state](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/state.html) keyword that might be a good fit for this situation:

```
sub foo {
    state $regex = /.../;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to complete `ikegami`'s great answer. Some more words I would like to waste on the definition of local variables in pre 5.10 [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).

Let's see a simple example code:

```
#!/bin/env perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

{ # local 
my $local = "After Crying";
sub show { print $local,"\n"; }
} # local

sub show2;

show;
show2;

exit;

{ # local 
my $local = "Solaris";
sub show2 { print $local,"\n"; }
} # local
```

The user would expect that both `sub` will print the local variable, but this is not true!

Output:

```
After Crying
Use of uninitialized value $local in print at ./x.pl line 20.
```

The reason is that `show2` is parsed, but the initialization of the local variable is not executed! (Of course if `exit` is removed and a `show2` is added at the end, `Solaris` will be printed in the thirds line)

This can be fixed easily:

```
{ # local 
my $local;
BEGIN { $local = "Solaris"; }
sub show2 { print $local,"\n"; }
} # local
```

And now the output what was expected:

```
After Crying
Solaris
```

But `state` in 5.10+ is a better choice...

I hope this helps!